# Import Vue as a browser module in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, module, nuxt.js

I'm trying to include Vue, vue-router, vue-meta, and vuex as browser modules from a CDN, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Nuxt. I tried setting the resolve alias for Vue to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.esm.browser.min.js but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!
David

Comment: Nuxt.js implements vue-router and vuex in its core

Comment: So is it impossible to load Vue with a CDN then? It seems like it should be possible.

Comment: You can set the cdn script in the `head` configuration - [configuration-head](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head)

Comment: Yes I've done that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide your error log ? more details